# Rails Devise only redirects to a fixed path. Need to redirect back where the user came from when authentication was triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

Working on a Ruby on Rails app with Devise.

Devise only redirects to a fixed path, root app path by default.
There are protected urls, and if the user click some links (e.g. "Ask Question" here), he is sent to the /sign_in page. On successful logon, the user is not sent back to the "Ask Question", but rather to "/".
Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: and yes, the request is POST, not GET
as I can see there's no way to store it:

    def store_location!
      session["#{scope}_return_to"] = attempted_path if request.get? && !http_auth?
    end

Comment: works fine here.. (rails 3.0.3, devise 1.1.3). Are you sure you are using the authenticate_user! before fiter and not something else?

Comment: Makinng the original request GET instead of POST resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makinng the original request GET instead of POST resolved the issue.
It was initially wrong to redirect to POST. Unfortuntely if the user was trying to update any data he will be forced to re-enter and re-submit, the solution here is to disallow users to enter any data which they will not be able to submit if they are not logged in.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I am using. It works ;)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.is_a?(User)
      "/welcome"
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to save the url on your session hash for it to work.

```
session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
```

Then redirect to it in your update action, after a successful save:

```
redirect_to session[:return_to]
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect users back to the page they were on when they clicked the Sign In link, I use:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    :back
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this method in your application_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  (session[:"user.return_to"].nil?) ? "/" : session[:"user.return_to"].to_s
end
```

Comment: session is almost empty {"_csrf_token"=>"mKFGVkp35fJKzjnsTwlRboadApBkae5z0xeVLXMycno=", "warden.user.user.key"=>["User", 1], "flash"=>{:notice=>"Signed in successfully."}}